# Multi-process iOS application

Tags: ios, opengl-es, process, webview

On iOS 6+, I have one application which is a WebView and when clicking on a special URL it starts an OpenGL view.

This can be done fairly simply, however what I need is for the OpenGL view to start in another process.

The OpenGL application is big and complex and could eventually compromise its own integrity. So the idea is that if/when it crashes it should return to the WebView instead of terminating and going back to the springboard.

While its fairly trivial to do on Android (and Windows/OSX) I couldn't find any information of how to do that on iOS, could someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Why not simply fix, so that OpenGL doesn't crash!

Comment: Of course that'd be the way in the general case, however here we need to play content that is user downloaded (its a kind of file type viewer) and although it won't crash most of the time we can't guarantee that all contents will be "crash safe".

Comment: Why can't you guarantee that, it's simply a matter of programming things the right way.

Comment: Because it runs a VM that is not specified by us and not fully documented.

Comment: NSExtension not the Multi-process？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have multi processes in an iOS app.

When an app crashes it always returns to the Springboard. There is one exception for VoIP apps, but that doesn't apply to your scenario and your app would be rejected if you would try that approach.

Comment: Thanks, we couldn't find another way either.